# Cannot normally boot Tails from USB on Clevo N857EK1

Tags: linux, boot, liveusb, tails

I cant normally boot Tails on my laptop.It start freezing when I press button Start (See photo) or when choosing Wi-Fi. Please see my Bios setting.I try with different settings but it doesnt help.Also the same situation when I try other USB ports,other USB drive.Also I write image to USB drive with UltraIso and Etcher (the same situation with both programs).I think problem is in BIOS.Please help me.

P.S.I have installed Linux from USB(but I think I was lucky because sometimes it also freeze)

Photos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIrTC.jpg

Comment: We can't see much in the picture, but since Tails loads and operates in RAM only, with no persistence (I think), it could be a RAM or video memory problem. Can you tell us more about your PC? Brand, model, how much RAM, dedicated video memory (as in, discrete GPU) or not, everything you can tell us about it can help us help you...

Comment: I have some problems with video adapter while installing Linux (Linux doesnt shut down it just turned off screen and all.But with newest Linux no problem more)

RAM:16GB 
2 video adapters:1-Intel,2-Nvidia GTX 1050ti 4GB

Comment: I haven't used Tails for some time, but I know that it's designed to be secure as all hell, hence some strange behavior on some machines. Have you tried to disable Secure Boot in the UEFI before running it? Disable CSM too, for good measure. You can re-enable them when you're done using Tails. Still looks like bad RAM to me, I don't know why. When in UEFI, can you check if all your RAM is accounted for, and what clock speed it's set on? EDIT: you might find some interesting info here: https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html

Comment: Secure boot is truned off.But when I boot linux the same freezing. With Windows-no problems.
How can I do that?

Comment: With previous Linux (18.04) I must set nomodeset option to boot normally

Comment: Well, you can try to add the same argument in your boot menu, but you'll have to do it every time. Worth a try. Tails, is, after all, based on Debian, same as Ubuntu.

Comment: it is set nomodeset by default.Without it even not booting